# Cannot show dialog in WPF .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

Following code

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{ 
            
}
```

works fine in a WPF project on .NET Framework but i cannot show a dialog in .NET Core.
The dialog flickers open for a split second then the program exits with: `has exited with code -2146232797 (0x80131623).`

This happens on any WPF .NET Core project but works fine in any .NET Framework project.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` is winforms class

Comment: i know but according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=netcore-3.1 this also applies to .net core. Is there any other way without using a dialog to pick a file

Comment: @Harry `OpenFileDialog` is available in a .NETCore WPF project. Does your project contain `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`?

Comment: @thatguy yes the project file contains that line. This is happening to me on any WPF core project, ive tried creating new ones to test in case i accidentally changed something in my project

Comment: Which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: BTW `OpenFileDialog ` is in WPF and in Win Forms. Your is from WPF, because `OpenFileDialog` from WinForms returns `DialogResult` not bool.

Comment: I just tried using a different PC and it works just fine, not sure what the problem is, I will try reinstalling visual studio on my PC that won't open a dialog